# Laravel - Undefined property: stdClass - search query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, stdclass

So I have this Laravel car project with search. I do my search with `DB::table()` query and it's working fine until I add `model relationship`. I will explain, here is my code.

This is my search `motoopremapretraga` function:

```
/**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     */
    public function motoopremapretraga(Request $request)
    {
        $autoQuery = DB::table('motoopremas');

        //pretraga - marka i model
        foreach ($request->only(['marka', 'model']) as $term => $value) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                continue;
            }
            $autoQuery->where($term, $value);
        }

        //pretraga - cijena od/do whereBetween
        if (
            $cijenaod = (int)$request->input('cijenaod')
            && $cijenado = (int)$request->input('cijenado')
        ) {
            $autoQuery->whereBetween('cijena', [(int)$cijenaod = $request->input('cijenaod'), (int)$cijenado = $request->input('cijenado')]);
        }

        //pretraga - vrsta cijene
        if ($vrsta_cijene = $request->get('vrsta_cijene')) {
            $autoQuery->where('vrsta_cijene', $vrsta_cijene);
        }

        //pretraga - grupa opreme
        if ($grupa_opreme = $request->get('grupa_opreme')) {
            $autoQuery->where('grupa_opreme', $grupa_opreme);
        }

        //pretraga - djelovi
        if ($tip = $request->get('tip')) {
            $autoQuery->where('tip', $tip);
        }

        //pretraga - ostecenje
        if ($ostecenje = $request->get('ostecenje')) {
            $autoQuery->where('ostecenje', $ostecenje);
        }

        //pretraga - zamjena
        if ($zamjena = $request->get('zamjena')) {
            $autoQuery->where('zamjena', $zamjena);
        }

        //pretraga - stanje
        if ($stanje = $request->get('stanje')) {
            $autoQuery->where('stanje', $stanje);
        }

        //vracanje rezultata
        $automobili = $autoQuery->get();

        return view('site.motooprema.pretraga')->with('automobili', $automobili);
    }
```

You see I'm using `DB::table('motoopremas')` to find my results from search, and at the end just `$automobili = autoQuery->get();` to specify my blade variable.

Okay then this is my `results blade view` really simple just to show if everything works fine:

```
@foreach($automobili->where('deleted_at', null) as $auto)
{{$auto->naslov}}
@endforeach
```

And everything is working fine, but when I add my relationship from my `Motooprema.php` model like this:

```
@foreach($automobili->where('deleted_at', null) as $auto)
<!-- this is my relationship -->
@if($auto->sifraMotoopremaaktivnosts->first()->status == 1)

{{$auto->naslov}}

@endif
@endforeach
```

It gives me **ERROR** like this:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$sifraMotoopremaaktivnosts
```

And this is my `Motooprema.php` model with this `sifraMotoopremaaktivnosts` relationship:

```
public function sifraMotoopremaaktivnosts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Motoopremaaktivnost::class, 'sifra_id', 'id');
    }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I need to have this search and this relationship is just showing activated car posts. What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DB::table` does not return a `Motooprema` class.

For this reason you cannot use relationship. ( `$auto->sifraMotoopremaaktivnosts`... )

Replace the `$autoQuery = DB::table('motoopremas');` line with `$autoQuery = Motooprema::query();` and it should return an instance of `Motooprema`.

Comment: I think it is working fine now, let me just check it out completely